# Magento 2 Meta tags sequence

Tags: magento2, meta-tags

where can change the order of the meta tags in Magento 2?
currently description meta tag & keywords meta tag showing before the title and are not in top of the page.

Comment: You need to add meta title before the meta description and meta keywords Right ?

Comment: Yes need to put title and description meta before keywords

Comment: Share current admin cms page meta field screenshot.

Comment: Default magento sequence is 1)Meta Title 2) Meta Description 3)Meta Keywords

Comment: I think you have customized or added custom module for meta?

Comment: No I do not think that the default order is correct in the default Luma theme, please confirm

Comment: Share your meta field screenshot. So I can check.